# Почему receiver не запускается автоматически

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, android-broadcastreceiver

Может быть я не правильно написал AndroidManifest:

```xml
<receiver android:name="com.example.myapplication.start" android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class start extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final String LOG_TAG = "autostart";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("onReceive start of background_start");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive " + intent.getAction());
        context.startService(new Intent(context, Background.class));
    }
}
```

Тестю на Galaxy A50, android 10

Comment: обрати внимание на [этот пост](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441442/10118835) для ресивера. там не используется категория интента, а пермишшен запрашивается от лица приложения. я бы перекинул пермишшен в приложение. какая у тебя версия андроида? ресивер в приложении, в сервисе или висит отдельно?
нет репы для комментов, пощу как ответ.

Comment: Тут слишком мало информации для точного ответа. Гугл часто меняет поведение для ресиверов. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts
Так же это могут менять и производители. Можно провести тест. Установить на эмуляторе. Обязательно запустить приложение, потом перезагрузить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receive.MyBroadcastReceiv"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" 
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Или попробуйте exported поменять на false.

Вы добавили разрешение?
Перед началом тега application добавьте теги

```
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
```